# "but" without contrast

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I've just read this paragraph:

> It remains to Husserl' s credit that he did not give in to the superficial 
>   pessimism which repeats itself in every age **but** which grew to a crescendo 
>   in the 1920's, nor did he simply pronounce solutions.

The word "but" is seemingly used without its usual contrasting. Is this OK or I'm missing something?

Comment: Always present to some extent but present to an unprecedented extent in the 1920s. Think of a graph: relatively flat, then climbing abruptly in the 20s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's contradiction there.  This "the superficial pessimism which repeats itself in every age but which grew to a crescendo in the 1920's," could be rephrased as

"There is a superficial pessimism which repeats itself in every age.  However, this repetition didn't repeat as normal in the 1920s, it grew to the strongest level it had ever been ("grew to a crescendo")."

So, the contradiction is in saying that the repetition wasn't normal.

Answer (score 0):

Correctamundo on the hidden contrast between "steady state" and "crescendo." But ... there's another red flag here, and one of my pet peeves *Crescendo* (portmanteau from Italian, by the way) means the *process* of rising in volume or intensity, not the fortissimo final loudness level. (The term is originally a musical one, but has expanded to mean any ballooning increase in metaphorical "size".) You don't "reach a crescendo" any more than you reach a footrace. Call me a prescriptionist curmumudgeon if you will, but definitions do avoid confusion and growing is not full size.